# polished function throws error only in test suite, not in actual app/browser

Tags: jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a button that utilises the `lighten` helper from `polished` (`styled-componenents`). I invoke it on hover like so:

FAB.styles.tsx

```js
&:hover,
&:focus {
    * {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    background: ${(props) => lighten(0.1, props.theme.primary)};
    transition: background 0.25s;
}
```

No errors, works exactly as intended.

When I try to test that component at all, I get the following error:

```sh
    Passed an incorrect argument to a color function, please pass a string representation of a color.

      41 |     }
      42 |
    > 43 |     background: ${(props) => lighten(0.1, props.theme.primary)} !important;
```

Why is this only throwing an error here when no such errors are thrown in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to wrapp your tests in a ThemeProvider. You can do this with a custom render method, similar to the one they show in the [testing-library docs on setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render).

```js
const Wrapper = ({ children }: any) => {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
};

export const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "wrapper">
) => render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...options });

export * from "@testing-library/react";
```

```js
it("renders something", () => {
    customRender(<Component />);
    const linkElement = screen.getByTitle(/Work with us/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I found the answer thanks to the help of Brian Hough, one of the maintainers of polished/styled-components. You can see our thread [here](https://github.com/styled-components/polished/issues/602).